# Keep image placeholder until drop with .sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am currently creating a small image gallery where I want to change the order of the images by dragging and dropping them, and when I do this I want to leave the image placeholder in place until I drop it somewhere

I am using this bit of code in my js (also ofc the html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sortableImages").sortable({
    start: function (e, ui) { ui.item.show();}
  });
})
```

When I am dragging the image, it doesn't leave a placeholder. What am I doing wrong? I have an ul with li's in there with the images in the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sortableImages" ).sortable({
  start: function (e, ui) { ui.item.show();},
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

use placeholder option in sortable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this in the sortable callback

```
placeholder: {
        element: function(clone, ui) {
            return $('<li class="selected">'+clone[0].innerHTML+'</li>');
        }
```